# Is std::decay_t<T> decay_copy(T&&) equivalent to auto decay_copy(auto&&)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, auto, template-argument-deduction

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3255.html defines `decay_copy` as follows:

```
template<typename T>
std::decay_t<T> decay_copy(T&& v)
{ 
    return std::forward<T>(v);
}
```

I just wonder:

**Is it equivalent to the following simpler one?**

```
auto decay_copy(auto&& v)
{
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It wasn't in 2011, because:

- We didn't have `auto` return type deduction for functions (that's a C++14 feature), and
- We didn't have `auto&&` parameters for functions (that's a C++20 feature), and
- Rvalue references were not implicitly moved from in return statements (that's also a C++20 feature)

But in C++20, yes, that is now a valid way to implement `decay_copy`. `auto` deduction does decay, `return v;` implicitly forwards, and everything else is the same.

---

I guess technically there's an edge case like:

```cpp
struct X {
    X();
    X(X&);
};
```

With the original formulation of `decay_copy(X{})`, this is ill-formed (there's no viable constructor for constructing an `X` from an rvalue `X`). With the new formulation under the existing C++20 rules, it becomes well formed and invokes the non-const copy constructor (because we do this [two-step overload resolution](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.copy.elision#3.sentence-3)).

If [P2266](https://wg21.link/p2266) is adopted though, then they would be exactly equivalent because `return v;` would *always* treat `v` as an rvalue, exactly as the existing formulation does.